# Clock divider simulation

Tags: vhdl

I've wrote this piece of code for a frequency divider in VHDL language and I don't understand why my frequency isn't divided when I simulate it. What I am doing wrong?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity div is
  port(clk                      : in  std_logic;
       clk1, clkafisare, clkorg : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture fct_div of div is
begin
  process(clk)
    variable c, e, g : integer   := 0;
    variable d, f, h : std_logic := '0';
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      e := e+1; c := c+1; g := g+1;
      if g = 12000000 and h = '0' then
        h := '1'; g := 0;
      elsif g = 12000000 and h = '1' then
        h := '0'; g := 0;
      end if;
      if c = 25000000 and d = '0' then
        d := '1'; c := 0;
      elsif c = 25000000 and d = '1' then
        d := '0'; c := 0;
      end if;
      if e = 100000 and f = '0' then
        f := '1'; e := 0;
      elsif e = 100000 and f = '1' then
        f := '0'; e := 0;
      end if;
    end if;
    clk1       <= d;
    clkafisare <= f;
    clkorg     <= h;
  end process;
end fct_div;
```

Comment: What are you getting and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simulation shows that your code actually does generate divided clocks, but
the large integers used in the division gives periods up to 500 ms when
dividing a 100 MHz clock, so you may not have waited long enough :-)

You can see the simulation below.

[image]

You can indeed store process state in process variables, since that state *is*
retained between suspensions of the process.  Note that the process is not
invoked between runs, like a ordinary software function, but simply suspended
at the end (when having a sensitivity list), and execution is then resumed at
an event at one of the signals in the sensitivity list.

Some comments to the code:

- The assign to `clk*` should go inside the `if rising_edge(clk)`, since you
  probably want these outputs to be from flip-flops.
- Consider using the state in `clk*` instead of the `d`, `f`, and `h`
  variables, since it is almost redundant.
- Consider making the counters with signal based on `std_logic_vector`, instead
  of the internal integer variables, since debugging is typically easier when
  using signals that can be shown easily in a waveform, and you have better
  control over the implementation.  For example when debugging, you would have
  seen that the counters actually incremented, and thus may have understood
  that the divider works, but the resulting clock just have a long period.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your last bullet point - Why not signals of type `integer` (or at the very least `unsigned`!)?  They are perfectly viewable as waveforms.  And with my version of modelsim, so are `variables`, I do this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the variables into architecture level signals and switch from variable assignments to signal assignments.

You should also move the assignment of clk1, clkafisare, and clkorg into the first if-statement to describe edge sensitive registers. If you don't have a testbench you'll also have to write one to generate the clk signal before you can get any output.

Comment: You can indeed store process state in process variables, since that state is retained between suspensions of the process.  See additional comments in my answer.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I got my wires crossed thinking about variables in subprograms.