# Cyclone II Board VHDL Clock Divider

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am busy trying to code a ping pong type game into my FPGA Board (Altera Cyclone II model) and there are two clocks, 50MHz and 27MHz. A clock is required for the game to work. I want to use the 50MHz clock but need to slow it down to 1Hz (the "ball" should only move one LED for every oscillation). I am a very new user to VHDL and FPGA and have done some research online but none have really helped me regarding the slowing down of the clock in VHDL.

My thinking is to use two loops, one for low and one for high and using 25000000 clock cycles for high and 25000000 clock cycles for low which will end up generating a 1Hz clock when using the 50MHz clock. I have no idea how to go about implementing it in VHDL though even though I know the non-code logic for it.

I checked a previous similar question: [Clock divider simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504998/clock-divider-simulation) but the person who posted the question did not include comments and I can't really follow what goes on in that code. Any help is highly appreciated!

Below is the code I have but I am not sure if it will work or not.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity pingpong is
port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    gameclk : out std_logic
);
end pingpong;

architecture behave of pingpong is  
begin
    process(clk)
    variable a : integer := 0;
    signal b : std_logic := '0';
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        a := a+1;
        if a = 25000000 and b = '0' then
            b := '1'; a := 0;
        elsif a = 25000000 and b = '1' then
            b := '0'; a := 0;
        end if;
    end if;
    gameclk <= b;

    end process;
end behave;
```

Comment: i am not sure if you can define a signal in a process. It would be suffient to simply count to 50000000, on then set gameclk to <=1. I undestand your need to have symetric '1' and '0' clk but it is not nessecary, since you are interested in the risign_edge.

Comment: You are right you cannot. I changed it to a variable instead. The code works now after I saw that mistake.
If I simply count to 50000000 as you suggested, it ends up making the clock 0.5Hz (the clock LED lights up for one full second before going off). It should only be on for half a second to signify "high" and off for half a second to signify "low".

Comment: An alternative to making a 1 Hz clock is to make an enable signal that is asserted at 1 Hz, and then still use the high frequency clock, but only update the state when the enable signal is asserted.  Usually you don't want too many clocks in a design, since clocks requires special handling and presents cross-clock-domain issues, so instead enable signals are often used.